# Why there exist error when I run npm install --no-bin-links?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I use :

Laravel 5.4

Windows 10

Node version : v6.11.1

Npm version : 5.3.0

If I run : `npm install --no-bin-links`

There exist error :

```
npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.11: express 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\node_modules\bs-recipes
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\node_modules\bs-recipes' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\node_modules\.bs-recipes.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\windows10\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-30T00_41_20_491Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve the error?

Update :

I uninstall Node version : v6.11.1 and install the new version, v8.4.0, but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this error but the console output clearly states:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\node_modules\bs-recipes' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\node_modules\.bs-recipes.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Try the following:

- Restart your computer.
- If you are using visual studio code, close it. And run `npm install` via console.
- If you are using visual studio code, update it to the latest version.
- Find that file in the error and rename it, as the error suggests.

> Tip: Always read the error message. Most of the time it will tell you what the problem exactly is.

**Update**

Try checking this similar issue on github: [npm 17444](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444)

Comment: Now it works. I using : `npm cache clean --force`. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951131/why-js-and-css-not-load-whereas-compile-asset-laravel-mix-success. I find the new problem